# Adding item to observableArray not updating view on jQuery button click

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to work out why the following example doesn't work.

The observableArray isn't updated until it is manually told that it has changed (using  valueHasMutated() ).

I thought the whole point of the observables was that when it changed the view is automatically updated.

```
<button type='button' id='add'>add</button>
<button type='button' id='mutated'>force update</button>
<div id="short_tasks" data-bind="foreach: list">
  <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ListTest = function () {

  this.list = ko.observableArray([{title: 'item1'}]);
}

var viewModel = new ListTest();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$('#add').click(function () {
  viewModel.list().push({title: 'new item'});
});

$('#mutated').click(function() {
  viewModel.list.valueHasMutated();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneWookie/HFgbR/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to call `push` directly on the observableArray, which will push your item to the underlying array and notify any subscribers.

```
viewModel.list.push({title: 'new item'});
```

Comment: Damn, thanks, worked perfectly. I knew I must have been missing something.